# Onclick or href which is best for opening an link in button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Which is the best method.To open an link using button

```
<button type="button" onclick="location='permalink.php'">Permalink</button>

<button type="button" href="index.php">Permalink</button>
```

Comment: There's no point in using JavaScript if you don't have to, especially for a basic hyperlink.

Comment: Don't use javascript if you can avoid it. It breaks all kind of unexpected places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use jquery you can write the second button like this

```
<button type="button" id="SecondButton" data-href="index.php">Permalink</button>
```

and then add some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SecondButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
        window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).data().href;
    });
</script>
```

Edit (Further completed scenarios)

```
<button type="button" id="SecondButton" data-href="index.php" onclick="location='permalink.php'" href="index.php">Permalink</button>
```

I would insert both additional href tag and onclick inside it too; you could then test for different scenarios; devices that do not support javascript or jquery fails to load on CDN like mobile etc:

```
<button type="button" id="SecondButton" data-href="index.php?trackAnalytics=1" onclick="location='permalink.php?trackAnalytics=2'" href="index.php?trackAnalytics=3">Permalink</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap, you can do this...

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="permalink.php">Permalink</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one should work, but inline scripts are not recommended. You should read about how to attach events using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for standards compliant browsers and [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for older IE.

The second won't work since [buttons don't use the `href` attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/button).

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can do something like this, if the button 'style' is what you're after, and not specifically the `<button>` tag:

```
<form method="link" action="permalink.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Permalink">
</form>
```

Another thought is that you could style an anchor to look like a button, then you could use the href attribute.

Comment: I do not think a complete form would be needed on this. This is not a good solution. You could have just posted "Hey, do `<a href="index.php" class="button">go</a>`" instead. -1

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Well no, your code snippet would not show a button in the browser's default style; that's merely an anchor with a style which you have not defined, which is exactly what I wrote as a second suggestion.