# Best Practice for JS - window.open() in href or in onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, compatibility

Just a question about optimization, between :

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.open('myUrl.com');">link-1</a>
```

and :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('myUrlBis.com');">link-2</a>
```

Is one better than the other ? Or more compatible ? Thanks.

Comment: Not really a duplicate of [Onclick or href which is best for opening an link in button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765363/onclick-or-href-which-is-best-for-opening-an-link-in-button) ;)

Comment: Neither is preferred. You should look into JavaScript event binding, and listen for the click on the link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best practice is to use [the `target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target):

```
<a href="http://myUrl.com" target="_blank">link-1</a>
```

If that doesn't suit, a `click` handler (ideally not assigned via attribute) would be my take.

Comment: Why is this the better practise?

Comment: @dwjohnston - It's semantic, so the browser (/screen reader, etc.) can indicate what's going to happen, and no JavaScript is required.

Answer (score 3):

Neither one

Make it a regular link using  `href` and `target`

```
<a id='my-link' target="_blank" href="http://myUrlBis.com">link-2</a>
```

If you need to do some processing of the click with JavaScript, you can use the following

```
document.getElementById("my-link").onclick = function(e) {
  // Do some processing here, maybe 
  window.location = this.href
  // Return false to prevent the default action if you did redirect with script
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript

```
<a target="_blank" href="myUrlBis.com">link</a>
```

With JavaScript

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" id="myLink">link</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function(){ //attach click event to link
        var winPop = window.open(this.href);  //`this` is reference to link, get href
        return false;  //prevent click event from clicking the link
    }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a9K23/)

Answer (score -1):

Below code should be fine.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="window.open(url)">
```

Found issue in IE (version:11) with below code

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.open(url)">
```

Problem: The parent window is getting refreshed in IE when we have javascript window.open code in href attribute.